# Create database in Azure Databricks using R dataframe

Tags: r, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have my final output in R dataframe. I need to write this output to a database in Azure Databricks. Can someone help me with the syntax? I used this code:

```
require(SparkR)
data1 <- createDataFrame(output)
write.df(data1, path="dbfs:/datainput/sample_dataset.parquet", 
   source="parquet", mode="overwrite")
```

This code runs without error, but i dont see the database in the datainput folder (mentioned in the path). Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: how do you check presence of the data? what command is used?

Comment: I just check here if a sample_dataset is created in the datainput folder. Not using any command to do so.

Comment: but what tool are you using to check? DBFS File Browser in DB UI?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [saveAsTable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/saveAsTable.html) function. `write.df` is particularly to save the data in a file system only, not to tag the data as table.

```
require(SparkR)
data1 <- createDataFrame(output)
saveAsTable(data1, tableName = "default.sample_table", source="parquet", mode="overwrite")
```

In the above code, `default` is some existing database name, under which a new table will get created having name as `sample_table`. If you mention `sample_table` instead of `default.sample_table` then it will be saved in the default database.